# Howto Configure Apache SSL and Tomcat in different servers?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, mod-jk, ajp

I am trying to configure a redirection from Apache to Tomcat, but with the difference that both Apache and Tomcat are installed in two different machines. I have got this working fine already using mod_jk (under Ubuntu Server 14), however issue comes when I have included SSL in the Apache side (lets call it Server1).

I have bought a Comodo SSL certificate and installed it fine in my Apache server which is now working and running under SSL with no issues. I have created a VirtualHost for port 443, including the same JKMount directives that for port 80 (Virtual Host :*.80), and the thing is that  when the Apache side is running under SSL port 443, and the user selects an option in the web application that would redirect the user to a web application under the Tomcat configuration in the Server2 and which is only running under normal HTTP, the SSL connection ends and the user continues working in a non secure way under HTTP:80 in this application.

With the JKMount directives and the worker.properties file in the Apache Server1 side, the user never realizes that it is moving from a Server to another,as the url goes from

> `http://example.com`

to

> `http://example.com/app1`

.... however with the actual SSL configuration I have, when the user is in the

> `https://example.com`

and moves to the other application in the tomcat Server2, moves to

> `http://example.com/app1`.

How can I do to keep the SSL connection in both sides?... I have tried using the same SSL Certificate in the Tomcat Server2 side, however if I do so, the user is not able to move from

> `https://example.com`

to anything as the screen gest blank.

Any ideas about how to get this configuration working?, How many certificates do I need?, one for each server?, if so how must I purchase the certificate for the

> `http://example.com/app1`

???

Thanks a lot in advance, here you can find the Virtual Host configuration in the Apache Server1 I have for SSL.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/myapplication
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin soporte@example.es
        ServerAlias example.com *example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXP56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/Apache_Comodo/example_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example_com.key
        JkMount /ExampleFrontend/* example
        JkMount /ExampleFrontend example
        JkMount /app1/* alfresco
        JkMount /app1 alfresco

   ProxyPass         /ExampleFrontend  http://example.com:8080/ExampleFrontend
        ProxyPassReverse  /ExapmpleFrontend  http://example.com:8080/ExampleFrontend



        <Directory "/var/www/example">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```